# Running A Java Eclipse Project on a Cloud-based Server with external Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, heroku, server

I hope this is the right place to post this question. The web applications stack exchange did not look suitable based on the other questions asked on there so I guessed this might be the best place to put this question.

I have a java eclipse project that works as I would like it which takes in an image locally from the adjacent file path and performs the required action on this image before returning a double value at the end after all the calculations. To do these calculations I use the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library which is essential to the core functionality of the application.

The issue I am having is to deploy this application so that the the application when it receives a request will take in an image (preferably as a .jpg but this can be changed if absolutely essential) and then after the application has carried out the required task send back the resulting number. In future this will be sent and received by an Android app which will just take the photo, compress it and send it away before receiving and displaying the answer but for now I'm just trying to get my project onto an accessible server.

I have tried to use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and followed their tutorials and instructions which encourages the use of Maven but I could not properly insert the dependencies for my project as it used an external jar. I spent a lot of time checking through the various solutions online to this issue but a lot of them felt like workarounds which only worked in some cases and none were working for me. I am open to using this again if there is an elegant solution that is simple to follow.

The main sections of this question that I am asking is for the simplest way to take my working eclipse project which uses an external library, modify it to take in an image via server request and then send back a number result. I also would like a suggestion as to which cloud-based service would be suitable for this project and allow me simply to put my code on their service and allow a test user to run this code whenever I want with reasonable availability.

Sorry for the long-winded explanation and I hope I have provided enough information. I have been trying to work out how to do these things with the help of tutorials and suggestions for a few weeks now but have no previous experience with making a web server as everything I have created has been a local program.

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: Does your Eclipse project have a web server? Are you already interfacing with it through a browser (locally)?

Comment: It does not. I wasn't able to build it properly through Maven when trying to run it on my local host